# Why the screen resolution is 1024x768?

Tags: user-research, users, ux-designer

Worldwide 1024x768 is still the most common screen resolution. Why they had chosen the width as 1024 and not a user remembrance number like 1020 or 1030?

Comment: Re-post of **[this](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/10619/when-did-1024x768-become-the-standard-desktop-screen-resolution)**

Comment: I've marked this as a duplicate because that question covers most of the same ground as this one. Also, you cite no evidence that 1024x768 is the most common resolution. On the contrary, [worldwide it appears 1366x768 is the most common](http://gs.statcounter.com/#desktop-resolution-ww-monthly-201304-201404). Nearly 3x as many machines run at that resolution than 1024x768.

Answer (score 4):

The resolution of 1024x768 has an aspect ratio of 4:3. If the width is 1030, the height would be 772.5 pixels and since there are no half pixels, 1030 pixels is not possible.
1020 pixels would be possible, but perhaps 1024 was the maximum amount of pixels they were technically able to fit inside a screen.

Comment: It is far more likely that 1024 was chosen because it is a power of 2. Hardware wise that is a lot easier to implement and doesn't waste anything.