# When designing for desktop, is it still appropriate to design for standard pixel density?

Tags: website-design, gui-design, screen-resolution

With new, high resolution monitors and laptops popping up all over the place I'm starting to wonder whether I should be making the desktop only design elements of my websites suitable for high pixel density displays. I haven't been able to find any solid stats on recent desktop resolution and would love input on the subject.

Answer (score 2):

I do web development, and I've recently switched to exclusively SVG for icons. Slightly fiddley to get set up but it works on all resolutions back to IE9. Much easier than handling 2+ resolution images. If a client wants to support IE8 I add the standard sprited graphics.

Comment: Icons are generally well-suited to vector formats like SVG; I recommend using SVG by default and only using a bitmap image when you have specific reasons for doing so. This applies to all digital mediums, not just web browsers.

Answer (score 0):

i recently took up a project and based my resolution decision on the table W3Schools provided:
http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_display.asp

statcounter might be able to help guide your decisions as well:
http://gs.statcounter.com/

also see this question for more: 
[When did 1024x768 become the standard desktop screen resolution?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/10619/when-did-1024x768-become-the-standard-desktop-screen-resolution?rq=1)

Comment: I would not refer to W3schools as "W3". It creates confusion with the authoritative World Wide Web Consortium (W3C at www.w3.org).

Comment: Confusion which may be deliberate on W3School's part - through deliberate action or inaction. (More on that at [w3fools](http://www.w3fools.com/))